# Outlook tasks folder delete issue

Tags: outlook, task, microsoft-graph-api

When deleting a task Folder in Outlook Tasks, the tasks under the deleted folder are still listed under the folder "Flagged Items and Tasks".

It occurs in Outlook Task UI and in the API.

Also, all the created tasks are marked as flagged by default.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: is there a question here or just a statement? This is something you'd need to address with the Outlook Tasks product group, as API can only behave how the product behaves.